# Using both global and local variables with multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to create a python script that utilizes parralel processing and uses both local variables from my args parser and shares two global variables to compute dataset moments.

In my previous code that worked without the global variables I had a structure like the following:

```python
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

def eval_function(args, file_name):
    # function that does stuff with args and filename.
    return
    
def main():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--some_arg")
    parser.add_argument("--path_to_folder")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    folder = os.listdir(args.path_to_folder)

    temp = partial(eval_function, args)

    with Pool(10) as pool:
        _ = pool.map(func=temp, iterable=folder)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Following some resources online I found that when initializing the worker and declaring the global variables with the Value function I can share a global variable within each process as shown below.

```python
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import os
from multiprocessing import Value, Pool
from functools import partial

def eval_function(s_mean, s_std, args, file_name):
    # function that does stuff with args and needs filename.

    # dummy operation on global s_mean and s_std. 
    with s_mean.get_lock():
        s_mean.value+=1
        print(s_mean.value)

    with s_std.get_lock():
        s_std.value+=1
        print(s_std.value)
        

def init_worker(shared_s_mean, shared_s_std):
    global s_mean
    global s_std
    s_mean = shared_s_mean
    s_std = shared_s_std


def main():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--some_arg")
    parser.add_argument("--path_to_folder")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    folder = os.listdir(args.path_to_folder)

    s_mean = Value(c_int, 1)
    s_std = Value(c_int, 1)

    temp = partial(eval_function, args)

    with Pool(10, initializer = init_worker, initargs=(s_mean, s_std, )) as pool:
        _ = pool.map(func=temp, iterable=folder)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem here is that this doesn't seem to work. Both the partial function and the initargs seem to rely on positional arguments. I've tried to pass the args to the init_worker function, but this also doesn't work.

With the above code I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
process_track() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'args' and 'filename'
```

Adding args to the initializer function also yields an error related to positional arguments.

Does someone know how to properly use global variables alongside with local variables and an iterable (filename in my case)?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `s_mean` and `s_std` as arguments of `eval_function`, use the global variables using the `global` keyword:

```py
def eval_function(args, file_name):
    global s_mean  # allows you to access a previously introduced global var
    global s_std
```

### Complete example

```py
from functools import partial
import multiprocessing as mp


def eval(args, file_name):
    global mean
    global std
    print(f"mean={mean}, std={std}, args={args}, file_name={file_name}")


def init(shared_mean, shared_std):
    global mean
    global std
    mean = shared_mean
    std = shared_std


if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder = ["a", "b", "c"]  # test values
    args = (1, 2, 3)
    mean = mp.Value("i", False)  # your code doesn't run on my machine here
    std = mp.Value("i", False)
    std.value = 10034  # for demonstration

    temp = partial(eval, args)
    with mp.Pool(10, initializer=init, initargs=(mean, std)) as pool:
        _ = pool.map(func=temp, iterable=folder)
```

This prints

```
mean=<Synchronized wrapper for c_int(0)>, std=<Synchronized wrapper for c_int(10034)>, args=(1, 2, 3), file_name=a
mean=<Synchronized wrapper for c_int(0)>, std=<Synchronized wrapper for c_int(10034)>, args=(1, 2, 3), file_name=b
mean=<Synchronized wrapper for c_int(0)>, std=<Synchronized wrapper for c_int(10034)>, args=(1, 2, 3), file_name=c
```

Comment: maybe consider adding in thee `if __name__ == "__main__":` idiom to your example for those of us not on linux?